# Move date from column1 to column 2 and column1 is set null

Tags: mysql

Any idea how to do this in MySQL?

Current data:

```
ID | name | lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3
1   justin  test
```

Desired outcome:

```
ID | name | lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3
1   justin         test
```

Comment: Do you want it in a specific rows? or all rows?

Comment: @sagi.. it in a specific rows

Comment: Specific ID = 1, or is there logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl SET lvl2 = lvl1, lvl1 = NULL WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the update statement should update all the rows of the table.

```
UPDATE tbl SET lvl2 = lvl1, lvl1 = NULL;-- works well on Oracle
```

Since MySql update only work with a where clause available, we have to add one like below.

```
UPDATE tbl SET lvl2 = lvl1, lvl1 = NULL WHERE id IS NOT NULL;
```

Here we assign the value of lvl1 to lvl2 and lvl1 to null where the id is null, i.e. those changes are made on every row of the table tbl.

If you want to perform the update only when lvl1 is not null try:

```
UPDATE tbl SET lvl2 = lvl1, lvl1 = NULL WHERE lvl1  IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I just added an explanation @PhiterFernandes!